# Does anyone know how to alter the font-size in the editing box using best_in_place gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-size, inline-editing, best-in-place

So I'm using the best_in_place gem to edit my form on the page.  I have a price like: $1234. when i click the price to edit it, the font becomes very small in comparison to the font I'm using in the form and it looks strange.  I'd like them to be the same.

Here is my code from the web inspector:
2345.0

changing the font on the class or id simply changes the size pre-editing.  once you click the text it shrinks again.  I guess I really need to know how to select the box on the page once I click to edit.

Comment: Try using "Inspect Element" in your browser to find out what is styling the input. Once you find that out, change it.

Comment: my code didn't come through, but that's what I did and it just gives me the element how it is before the click.  <span class="best_in_place" id="best_in_place_address_387_price" data-url="/addresses/387" data-object="address" data-attribute="price" data-type="input" data-original-content="2345.0">2345.0</span> . styling any of this just changes the font before it is clicked to edit.  once clicked then it all shrinks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the class to the input field itself, so the class only gets applied to the input, not the label, by using:

```
<%= best_in_place @your_variable, :name, { :inner_class: => "your_class" } %>
```

Then the css is a simple

```
.your_class { font-size: 14px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to add class to the span which best_in_place helper generates and then apply styling to the input nested within.

First add class to the best_in_place field:
`<%= best_in_place @your_variable, :name, { :classes => "input_field" } %>`

(I work with best_in_place 2.1.0, for older version you would need to depend on the id of the field, which seems to be unique)

Then apply styling to the **input** child of the class in your css:

`.input_field input {
    font-size: 12px;
}`